# Отловить клик на изометрическом тайле. Isometric social games

Tags: javascript, разработка-игр, геометрия

В книге [Social isometric games](http://www.kings.k12.ca.us/tempdocs/making_isometric_social_real_time_games_with_html5_css3_and_javascript.pdf), на странице 53, описывается метод определения тайла по кардинатам мыши. Все работает, но не понятно по какому принципу это рассчитано. Может кто то детально объяснить этот алгоритм? Может ссылочки на формулу имеются. Или хотя бы в какой области науки это искать.

Пример части кода, который интересует:

```
var col = (e.clientY - gridOffsetY) * 2;  //???
col = ((gridOffsetX + col) - e.clientX) / 2;  //???

var row = ((e.clientX + col) - tile.height) - gridOffsetX; //???
```

Comment: "Или хотя бы в какой области науки это искать." - капитан подсказывает, что в геометрии.

Comment: Ничего сложного на самом деле. Попробуйте для интереса сами придумать как преобразовать координаты экрана в координаты тайла, примерно такие же функции получаться.

Comment: Не, не могу догнать. почему мы точку по Y умножаем на 2? почему именно на 2!? и как вообще можно из Y вычитать X... это же разные оси.